# How to break a while loop with a hotkey

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I'm trying to break the while loop in function execute with an outdoor hotkey(cmd + esc), is there a way to do that?

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time

COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.cmd, keyboard.Key.ctrl}

current = set()
keyb = keyboard.Controller()

def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            execute()
            
def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass
    
def execute():
    while True:
        print("")

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: What is an "outdoor hotkey"?

Comment: maybe not that elegant, but you can declare a global variable that is by default set to `True`, then change it to `False` upon keypress. The while loop then just needs to check if that global variable is till `True`, otherwise terminate.